# two margin comparison and one conclusion?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, pattern-recognition, marginal-distribution

I read following notes, and couldn't get it. any idea or hint would highly appreciated.

a SVM classifier using a second order polynomial kernel. The first polynomial kernel maps each input data x to $ \phi_1(x)=[x, x^2]$ . The second polynomial kernel maps each
input data x to $ \phi_2(x) = [2x, 2x^2]$

my question is how we reach the following conclusion?

> In general, is the margin we would attain using $ \phi_2(x)$ is
>   **greater** in comparison to the margin resulting from using $ \phi_1(x)$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144272/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40936/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of $\phi_2$ is twice that of $\phi_1$, all the distances in $\phi_2$-space are twice as big as the distances in $\phi_1$-space. This means that the margin (which is roughly the "thickness" of the separating hyperplane that the SVM learns) is twice as big also. We can show this with an even simpler pair of kernel functions, $\phi_1(x, y) = (x, y)$ and $\phi_2(x) = (2x, 2y)$--the principle is exactly the same as with the pair of kernels you suggested.

If you have a dataset with positive points at $(0,0), (0,1)$ and negative points at $(1,0), (1,1)$, then using $\phi_1$ you'll learn the following SVM:

[image: SVM on the identity map]

On the other hand, $\phi_2$ multiplies each coordinate by 2 relative to $\phi_1$, so you learn the following hyperplane instead:

[image: SVM on 2*identity map]

As you can see, because all distances are inflated by a factor of 2, the margin is greater as well.

### Appendix: R code for plots

```
do.plot <- function(D, main, sub) {
    plot(NA, xlim=c(-0.5, 2.5), ylim=c(-0.5, 2.5), xlab='x', ylab='y', main=main, sub=sub)
    points(c(0, 0), c(0, D), pch='+')
    points(c(D, D), c(0, D), pch=4)
    abline(v=0, lty=2)
    abline(v=D, lty=2)
    abline(v=D/2)
}
do.plot(1, 'phi1', 'margin=1')
do.plot(2, 'phi2', 'margin=2')
```

Comment: I say margin is greater with factor 4, two on each coordinate. am I Wrong?

Comment: You are--the margin only extends in one direction. (In the example case, it is the thickness of the hyperplane along the x-axis, for instance.) So although I rescaled each coordinate, in this case it's only the rescaling of the *x* coordinate that expands the margin. The map $\phi_3(x, y) = (x, 2y)$ would produce the same margin as $\phi_1$.

Comment: so we should say increase margin by factor 2 on each coordinate?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "increase margin by factor 2 on each coordinate".

Comment: $ \phi_2 $ has double margin (factor 2) on each coordinate  espect to $ \phi_1 $ ?

Comment: The margin is not a property of $\phi_2$. $\phi_2$ is just a function between coordinate spaces. The margin is a property of the way the SVM separates the positive and negative classes. So one shouldn't say "$\phi_2$ has [a] margin" at all.

Comment: But yes, if you treat the margin as a vector, then the margin of the SVM with kernel $\phi_2$ on the given dataset is greater in each coordinate by a factor of 2, whereas the margin of the SVM with kernel $\phi_3$ is greater by a factor of 2 in the $y$-coordinate only.